# MS Word - Restrict header selection in header to current section

Tags: ms-word

I am compiling a collection of books in a large docx file and I have a problem.
In the headers and footers, the section names are displayed through the heading styles ("Heading 1","Heading 2","Heading 3",) like this: { STYLEREF "Heading 1" * MERGEFORMAT }.

The problem is the following. The next section headers grab the nearest previous heading from the previous section.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf8B3.jpg)

Who knows how to limit the choice of headings to the current section?

Nothing helps.  It grabs previous section.

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.